# onResume called for background activity when showing transparent activity

Tags: android, themes, transparent, activity-lifecycle

I have a requirement that asks to call an API from **onResume** of **Activity-A** and its response is used to block users from using the app if required by showing an **Activity-B** on top of **Activity-A**.

Another requirement was to have a few messages in the middle of **Activity-B's** UI and have the rest of the screen of **Activity-B** transparent. These messages show the user why they were blocked and redirect them to a URL to get themselves unblocked.

When the user returns from the redirected URL, the same API is called from **Activity-B's** **onResume** to check the current status.

Now the problem is, whenever the app is brought back from the background to the foreground when **Activity-B** is showing, **onResume** of **Activity-A** is also called which causes a double API call.

I've used the following theme style to make my **Activity-B** transparent:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Transparent.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

and then setting this theme in the manifest of **Activity-B**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in **Activity-B**

```
public void onPause(){
    finish();
    super.onPause();
}
```

This will finish **Activity-B** and the next time the user goes back to the app **Activity-A** will handle the api call like normal and recreate **Activity-B** if necessary.

Although I don't know your specific use case but you could just have a `GONE` overlay that is the size of the screen. When the user is not supposed to use the app the overlay is then set to `VISIBLE`. All actions are consumed by the overlay instead of the views beneath it effectively locking the user out and you would avoid a whole extra activity.

Comment: And about the Overlay situation. I simplified the Usecase to only Activity-A but I have multiple flows with this exact scenario so adding overlay from all those activities would have required a lot more work.